# Self Contradictory or tautologous Biconditionals

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If I have a statement, i.e., (G → ∼Q) ↔ ∼(Q • G), would it be accurate to call this statement self-contradictory?

On the left side, it is not the case that Q is true given that G is true.

On the right side, it is the case that Q and G are both false.

Thus I have a contrary, correct?

However, I am being asked if this statement is consistent, self contradictory, tautologous, contingent, or logically equivalent. I am thinking that perhaps it is tautologous, since it "jives" according to the traditional square of opposition as being a contrary?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mis-translated the right-hand expression (assuming the dot operator is 'and').  The expression does NOT mean 'G and Q are both false', it means 'G and Q are not both true'.  So, for example, that expression will be true when G is true and Q is false - which incidentally also makes the left-hand expression true.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful $$\lnot (G\land Q) \not\equiv (\lnot G \land \lnot Q)$$  Rather, by DeMorgan's rules, we know that $$\lnot (G \land Q) \equiv \lnot G \lor \lnot Q$$

(See [DeMorgan's Law(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

$$ $$

Now, we have that
$${(G → \lnot Q)} \equiv \lnot G \lor \lnot Q \equiv \lnot Q \lor \lnot G \equiv \color{blue}{Q \rightarrow \lnot G}$$
$$ $$
And we have that 
$$\lnot(Q \land G) \equiv  \lnot Q \lor \lnot G \equiv \color{blue}{Q\rightarrow \lnot G}$$

$$  $$

Can you make some conclusions about, $(G\rightarrow \lnot Q) \iff \lnot(Q \land G)?\,$

Comment: I would say that it must be a tautologous statement, correct?

Comment: Yes it is, indeed.

Comment: And the two sides of $\iff$ are logically equivalent.  The statement as a whole is tautologous.